# AWS Polly - How to name files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, amazon-polly

I'm currently trying to name the files that AWS Polly generates and stores in S3. OutputS3KeyPrefix adds only a prefix.

What keys I tried so far:

```
var params = {
      OutputS3Key: params.Text, 
      OutputS3KeyPrefix: params.Text,
      Key: params.Text,
      OutputFileName: params.Text,
      OutputFormat: "mp3",
      OutputS3BucketName: AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
      Engine: "neural",
      Text: params.Text,
      TextType: "text",
      VoiceId: "Amy",
      SampleRate: "24000",
    };
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

AWS Polly doesn't provide that feature. Only thing you can do, is adding a prefix. It's possible to change the file names in S3, but that's not the wanted solution.